# How to add some time between a user can create a report?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I need to set a timer like 5 minutes between a user can make a report, it is possible?Here is what I have tried, but with no success. In my table I have `created_at` column, and I want to display a message:`Report created within the last 5 minutes`, if the report is made in the last 5 minutes.

**Here is my controller**

```php
public function careerReportCareerSolution(requ $request)
{
    $reportExists = \App\Reports::where('user_id', $request['user_id'])
        ->whereDate('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(5)->toDateTimeString())
        ->exists();

    if($reportExists) {
        // report has been created within 5 minutes
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['error', 'Report created within the last 5 minutes']);
    }

    $report = \App\Reports::create([
        'user_id' => $request['user_id'],
        'username' => $request['username'],
        'user_id_posted' => $request['user_id_posted'],
        'username_posted' => $request['username_posted'],
        'career_solution_id' =>$request['career_solution_id'],
        'subject' =>$request['subject'],
        'why_reporting' =>$request['why_reporting'],
        'why_reporting_message' =>$request['why_reporting_message'],
        'additional_message' =>$request['additional_message'],
        'comment' =>$request['comment'],
        'comment_user' =>$request['comment_user'],
        'comment_id' =>$request['comment_id'],
    ]);
    $id = $request['career_solution_id']; // looks like this is the ID you ar looking for

    $career = CareerSolution::findOrfail($id);
    $career->active = $request['active'];
    $career->save();

    if ($report != "") {
        flash('Career solution report submited', 'success');
    } else {
        flash('Career solution report', 'warning');
    }

    return Redirect::back();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this? It look like some dirty hack :)

Comment: visually compare the values of your created_at column and the datetime produced by  Carbon (with dd or var_dump or echo). It might be a timezone difference.

Comment: @freeek because I don't want to let my users abusing of report system :) that's all

Comment: @MrEvers I will check soon:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there
I think you should use it like this may be the error in the eloquent query. Try something like this

```
$lastReport = \App\Reports::where('user_id', $request['user_id'])
                                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                                ->first();
$lastReportOn = time() - \Carbon\Carbon::parse($lastReport->created_at)->timestamp;

    if($lastReportOn < 300 ) {
        // report has been created within 5 minutes
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['error', 'Report created within the last 5 minutes']);
    }
```

Something like this can help you  if still not resolved please revert me.